Cloned Discord app doesn't respect the system's auto-rotation setting
On a realme gt master edition with Android 13, I have used the app cloning feature from the system to create a clone of the Discord app. This cloned instance always turns into landscape mode when I'm tilting my phone even-though the auto-rotation setting is disabled. This does not happen on the "main" version of the app.
After browsing a little I found that there was a related bug in Discord about one year ago, and when testing with other application it seems that the clones respect the rotation setting properly. This therefore seems to be a Discord-specific issue.
Is there any workaround I can use to block it from going into landscape mode?
